# 日本語に違和感: 投票がが記録されました

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

文脈: 「閉じる」票を入れた後に表示されるポップアップ

[image: 投票がが記録されました]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 投票内容を記録しました